# Setup usbip on Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: server, usb, 18.04, ip

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 server on an intel nuc an try to setup usbip to have remote access to a ZWave USB device connected to a raspberry pi. I loaded kernel modules with

```
modprobe usbip-core
modprobe vhci-hcd
```

After

```
sudo usbip attach -r 192.168.3.182 -b 2-2.2
```

i get

```
libusbip: error: udev_device_get_sysattr_value failed
usbip: error: open vhci_driver
usbip: error: query
```

Tried the steps above with linux Mint running in a virtual machine and everything works fine. Any suggestions? Thx in advance :).

Comment: If you still have this issue, please edit your question to include the complete output of `usbip --debug list -r 192.168.3.182`. I've seen this kind of error when the Pi server simply isn't responding and needs to be rebooted. I've also seen it in laptops where usbip broke suspend, and the laptop needs to be rebooted. The --debug output usually helps to narrow the cause of the error.